# java sent HTTP get request to meteor server

Tags: java, meteor

Question 1: Does Meteor server accept http get request from external client like my java app? 
Question 2: If Meteor server accepts http get request, how do I set up a method to process and respond it in meteor server? I have figure it out how to send a https get request in java. Please give me a sample of that server method.

Edited: I found a middleware way to do that,

```
  WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(0, 0, {
      route: '/api/endpoint',
      handle: function(req, res, next) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end('{"success": true}');
      },
  });
```

I try to put this in my meteor server, but i cant figure it out how it works...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Iron Router package, you can make a server-side route to handle HTTP requests: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#restful-routes

```
Router.route('/webhooks/stripe', { where: 'server' })
  .get(function () {
    // GET /webhooks/stripe
  })
  .post(function () {
    // POST /webhooks/stripe
  })
  .put(function () {
    // PUT /webhooks/stripe
  })
```